# Word Automation's SaveAs does not save the file in a particular folder in one machine

Tags: delphi, office-automation

I am facing a problem on a code that worked for years on a specific Win10 machine.

The function where the problem occurs is the following one:

```
   Function  SaveAsTextFile(sFile :String):String;
    const
      vi_wdFormatText = 2;
    var
      Word, Doc : OleVariant;
      NewFileName,FileName : String;
      sFileName,sExt, SPath : String;
    begin
      Result := '';
      Word := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
      try
        FileName := sFile;
        sFileName := ExtractFileName(sFile);
        sExt := ExtractFileExt(sFile);
        SPath := ExtractFilePath(sFile);
        NewFileName := CompletePath(sPath)+ Copy(sFileName,1,Length(sFileName)-Length(sExt))+'.txt';
        Word.Visible := False;
        Doc := Word.Documents.Open(FileName);
        Word.ActiveDocument.SaveAs( NewFileName, vi_wdFormatText);
        Word.ActiveDocument.Close(wdDoNotSaveChanges);
        Result := NewFileName;
      finally
         Word.Quit(wdDoNotSaveChanges);
         Word := Unassigned;
      end;
    end;
```

There are no exceptions at runtime, anyway the txt file that shuold be created by

`Word.ActiveDocument.SaveAs( NewFileName, vi_wdFormatText);`

doesn't appear in the specified folder.
The folder is an `AppData\Local` folder and the problem occurs only on one specific machine that apparently has nothing special, in fact there is a twin machine that behaves well.

The Word version is 2019 ('1912' specifically).

Please notice that if i use `c:\temp` instead of `Appdata` folder the function works normally.

Is it possible that Office Automation is restricted on a specific machine?

May you please give some useful pointers?

Comment: What's the *exact* path and filename you're trying to save to? Otherwise, the value of `NewFileName`?

Comment: c:\users\Myuser\AppData\Local\Myapp\Documents\currentuser\1234.txt

Comment: I would suggest to use ProcessMonitor to spy on the file system action done by your program and/or Word to be sure the accessed path is really the one you think.

Comment: Just to be sure: you have checked the the directory exists and the file doesn't exists yet.

Comment: the code works well on any other machine, only on one specific windows 10 pc i  am having problems. On this pc SaveAs is not saving the txt file, therefore the rest of the code does not work.

Comment: It's more likely a permissions issue on the problem machine.  Have you checked that the account your app is running on has write permissions there?

Comment: On the concerned PC check if the AppData path is redirected to another path (e.g. to a server path). See also here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/folder-redirection/folder-redirection-rup-overview